# how to read data from .xlsx file with exceljs

Tags: node.js, feathersjs, exceljs

I am sending a .xlsx file through body form-data with key=excel, type=file, and value=text.xlsx. I want to read the values obtained from the excel file.

```js
async create(data, params) {
    console.log(data);
    const { file } = data; // Assuming the file is sent as 'file' in form-data
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    
    console.log(file);
    console.log(data);

    await workbook.xlsx.load(file.data); // Load the Excel file from binary data
    const worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]; // Select the first worksheet
    
    const rows = [];
    worksheet.eachRow((row, rowNumber) => {
      const rowData = {};
      row.eachCell((cell, colNumber) => {
        rowData[`col${colNumber}`] = cell.value;
      });
      rows.push(rowData);
    });
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo code will work

Save as `demo.js`

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

async function create(data, params) {
    const { file } = data;
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    
    await workbook.xlsx.load(file.data);
    const worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
    
    const rows = [];
    worksheet.eachRow((row, rowNumber) => {
        const rowData = {};
        row.eachCell((cell, colNumber) => {
            rowData[`col${colNumber}`] = cell.value;
        });
        rows.push(rowData);
    });

    return rows;
}

async function processDataFile() {
    try {
        // Read the data.xlsx file
        const fileData = fs.readFileSync('data.xlsx');

        const data = {
            file: {
                data: fileData
            }
        };

        const params = {};

        const rows = await create(data, params);

        console.log('Data read successfully:', rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing data file:', error);
    }
}

processDataFile();
```

##### Input data

Save as `data.xlsx`

[image]

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install fs exceljs
```

##### Run it

```
node demo.js
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: @Nwp _  Thanks for your accept , can you give me up vote too?